# returning a C++ reference variable

Tags: c++

I am trying to understand this code:

```
int& getInt()
{
    static int i = 5;
    return i;
}

int main()
{
    int a = getInt(); // function return variable by reference,but `a` is a copy of the variable returned by function
    int& aa = getInt(); // `aa` is a reference of the variable returned by function

}
```

Would you please explain this?

Comment: The code does exactly what it does. Which part of it is unclear and not explained by your C++ text book?

Comment: I feel if you read your own comment 10 times, you could understand it. :)

Comment: `int& aa = getInt1();` surely :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`a` is a normal, non-reference variable. So assignment looks as

```
value_type = reference_type
```

That simply makes the value referenced by the return of `getInt` (thus, the value of `i`) to be copied into `a`.

In the second case, you are creating a reference with a reference, which "copies" the reference and makes `aa` point to the `static i`.

---

Funny enough, this might be easier to understand with a user class rather than a builtin type, because you can then specify all the constructors yourself and trace them. In that case, a copy constructor, typically looking like:

```
class A { public: A(A const& a); };
```

is called *when the new value of type A* is created. In the second case, *no new value* appears, and that's the key to understanding this example, I think.

Answer (score 0):

in the first case int a; it is receiving the address of static i , which is not useful here, But in the second case aa is of address type, or we can say that it is also reference type so it can take address and value is easily accessed by it. But in case of a; value is not actually present in a,, it is referring through & to I. But in second case it actually presents at &aa.